# What is the correct data structure to return from rest api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I want to do REST api to my clients.

Should I return my data wrapped as an object or just the data? what are the guidelines?

for  `/products`:

This:

```
  res.json({ products: [{ ... }] });
```

or that:

```
  res.json([{ ... }]);
```

Comment: Since the API is already `products`, the second one makes better sense.

Comment: I'd expect the second form, but the first has merit if it's ambiguous what the result is, or if other metadata might be included.

Comment: I would suggest instead of sending direct data in the API, send metadata as well as code, message, and data. Create a Response structure for application and use for all responses. 



    res.json({
        code: 'Some code',
        message: 'Success message'.
        data:[{ ... }]
    });

Comment: @RahulSharma I would suggest only sending this format with metadata while the status is not `200`, to keep the API clean. Since status code and error messages are for serving the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one object to respond then in this scenario you can use this

```
res.json([{ ... }]);
```

but if you have multiple object to return then you can use this

```
res.json({ products: [{ ... }], products2: [{ ... }] });
```